# shade colors in seaborn by category

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a pandas data frame with two categories.

```
%pylab inline

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns; sns.set();sns.set_style("whitegrid")

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df['category'] = df['A'].mod(2)
df['category_2'] = df['B'].mod(3)
df
```

when plotting it this way:

```
sns.lineplot(x='C', y='D', data=df, hue='category', size='category_2', style='category_2')
```

the color is constant for all the 0/1 values of `category`.
However, instead, I want to specify a specific color (range) for the two values of `category` and have hue generate this color range for 0/1 depending on the numeric size of `category_2`.

## edit

looks like a nice first try:

```
sns.relplot(x="D", y="D", hue="category", size="category_2",
                palette=["b", "r"], sizes=(10, 100),
                col="category", data=df)
```

but what is missing is:

- they should be below and not next to each other. EDIT: this can be solved by setting `col_wrap=1` - or even better: using `row` directly
- the colors are binary and not shaded, i.e. I would want to overlay them to compare them better

Comment: Could you add the images for what your two pieces of code generate? I think I have a similar question as yours.